# Fill in missing zipcodes by randomly selecting one from the neighbourhood

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe like below and I'm trying to replace missing values in the zipcode field by selecting any random value from a similar neighbourhood_group_cleansed. Below is my attempt but this does not work quite well. Please help.

```
zipcodes = a_df[['neighbourhood_group_cleansed','zipcode']].drop_duplicates().reset_index()
a_df['zipcode'] = a_df.apply(lambda row: np.random.choice(zipcodes[zipcodes['neighbourhood_group_cleansed'] == 
                row['neighbourhood_group_cleansed']]['zipcode']) if len(row.zipcode) == 0   else row.zipcode, axis = 1)

state   city    smart_location  neighbourhood_group_cleansed    zipcode
0   NY  New York    New York, NY    Manhattan   10029
1   NY  Brooklyn    Brooklyn, NY    Brooklyn    11221
2   NY  Brooklyn    Brooklyn, NY    Brooklyn    11206
3   NY  New York    New York, NY    Manhattan   10001
4   NY  New York    New York, NY    Manhattan   10162
... ... ... ... ... ...
6492    NY  New York    New York, NY    Manhattan   10004.0
6493    NY  Brooklyn    Brooklyn, NY    Brooklyn    11229.0
6494    NY  Queens  Queens, NY  Queens  11691.0
6495    NY  New York    New York, NY    Manhattan   10044.0
6496    NY  Brooklyn    Brooklyn, NY    Brooklyn    11234.0
```

Comment: can you show what error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
df['zipcode'] = df.apply(lambda x: random.choice(df[df['neighbourhood_group_cleansed'] == x['neighbourhood_group_cleansed']].zipcode.dropna().values) if np.isnan(x['zipcode']) else x['zipcode'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.